# https turns to http when redirecting from one jsp page to other

Tags: jsp, ssl

My application runs in SSL now, in one of my JSP pages I have used `response.sendRedirect("xyz.jsp");`, so now when redirect occurs HTTPS is converted to HTTP. How should I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest using a HTTP debugger such as Fiddler or HttpFox to check the value of the 'Location' header that is returned. This will enable you to confirm whether its a browser or server problem.

Comment: Is "xyz.jsp" constrained using <user-data-constraint> & <transport-guarantee> in deployment descriptor?

Answer (score 3):

quick and dirty: add the following lines at the beginning of xyz.jsp

```
if(request.getScheme().equals("http")){  
            String redirect = "https://<your domain>/<path>/xyz.jsp"; 
            response.sendRedirect(redirect);  
}
```